# Aligment of Items in nested ItemsControls

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

I have two ItemsControls nested within a single ItemsControl. Each are placed next to each other in Grid Columns with horizontally oriented StackPanel ItemsPanelTemplates so their contents are layer out horizontally.

While I want the two ItemsControls to occupy the full width of the parent, (50:50), I want the items within them to be right, and left aligned respectively... so they both are centred, something like (excuse my attempt at ASCII art):

```
|     LH ItemsControl           |     RH ItemsControl       |
|                       [][][][]|[][][]                     |
```

Here's my code so far, I have been tweaking the HorizontalAlignment attributes but if I get them to occupy the centre, then the two StackPanels don't fill the full width of the parent.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Things}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding LeftThings}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="LightPink" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="37"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding RightThings}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="LightBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="37"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Any ideas?

Rich

Comment: have you tried HorizontalAlignment="Left" on the L ItemsControl's Panel.
and orizontalAlignment="Right" on the R ItemsControl's Panel ?

FYI , Stretch is the default value you do not need to explicitly set it.

Comment: Thanks for replying @eranotzap but I'm afraid that gives me the items in the correct layout (centred to each other), but the StackPanel doesn't occupy the full width of the parent.

Comment: Why do you need it to ..? 
StackPanel only occupies the space is needs..

Comment: Fair enough, I want to be able to set a background colour on the space that the ItemsControl can occupy rather than the items themselves. Have set the Background property on the ItemsControl instead and this is doing what I'm after, cheers.

Comment: and settings the listbox background doesn't do the trick ?

Comment: I'm not using a ListBox, I'm using an ItemsControl, which I've set the Background on now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the Background property on the ItemsControl rather than the StackPanel and setting Orientation to Left and Right respectively on the StackPanel gave me the effect I was after:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Things}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding LeftThings}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="LightPink">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="37"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding RightThings}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="LightBlue">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use FlowDirection=RightToLeft on left stackpanel, and FlowDirection=LeftToRight in DataTemplate control. I made a sample. Below code can be used as is :

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfItemsControl.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="407.895" Width="884.211">
<Grid>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Names}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" Grid.Column="0">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Background="DarkGoldenrod" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                    <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" Grid.Column="1">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                                    </StackPanel>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Background="DarkGoldenrod" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>            
    </ItemsControl>     

</Grid>
 </Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfItemsControl
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = new DataStore();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }
}

public class DataStore
{
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }

    public DataStore()
    {
        Names = new List<string>();

        Names.Add(">");
        Names.Add(">");
        Names.Add(">");
        Names.Add(">");
        Names.Add(">");
    }
}
```

}

This code puts both side items in center, and  stretches both stackpanels.

Comment: Don't use flow direction to align elements, this will change the direction the elements will be laid out. Just change the ">" names to different values like "1"  "2" "3" "4" "5" to see what it does.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and example, but as @NovitchiS said this reverses the order which I'd rather not happen.